# How to avoid duplication while appending

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm writing a config bash script to build some environment on my Ubuntu.

One thing that needs to be done in this bash script is to append a function into `~/.bashrc` so that it could be executed automatically while logging.

However, for some reason, this script might be executed several times. As a result,  the same function is appended into `~/.bashrc` many times.

Is there a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of blindingly appending, check if it's there or not already.

something like `grep -q theFunction .bashrc || echo " theFunction() { .... } " >> .bashrc`